How to create a multiple bar chart in Python to display data for different categories per municipality?
I'm working on a project where I need to visualize demographic data for different municipalities in a multiple bar chart in Python. I have a dataset containing information about total population, female population, and male population for several municipalities in Mexico. Here are an example of data:
  NOM_MUN   POBTOT  POBFEM  POBMAS
Monterrey  1142994  578189  564805
  Apodaca   656464  324951  331513
Guadalupe   643143  324150  318993

I would like to create a bar chart where each municipality has three bars corresponding to total population, female population, and male population. How can I do this using libraries like Matplotlib or Seaborn in Python?
I tried to call with this code:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 16))
bar_width = 0.25
index = range(len(df_sorted))

bars1 = ax.bar(index, df_sorted['POBTOT'], bar_width, label='Total Population')
bars2 = ax.bar([i + bar_width for i in index], df_sorted['POBFEM'], bar_width, label='Female Population')
bars3 = ax.bar([i + bar_width * 2 for i in index], df_sorted['POBMAS'], bar_width, label='Male Population')

ax.set_xlabel('Municipality')
ax.set_ylabel('Population')
ax.set_title('Population by Municipality')
ax.set_xticks([i + bar_width for i in index])
ax.set_xticklabels(df_sorted['NOM_MUN'], rotation=45, ha='right')
ax.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

But doesn't visualize how I expected, how I can fix it?
Poblation chart

Are you using Pandas? df.set_index('NOM_MUN').plot(kind='bar') is a good start.

Thank you, shows only the values in the POBTOT column, how I can make a visualization with rest of the values like POBMAS and POBFEM?

The code seems to work fine for the data you provided even if you duplicate it to simulate more cities.

@MidasEstanislao Oh, it shows all three columns for me. Maybe your POBMAS and POBFEM columns are the wrong dtype? If it's any help, check out How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

With code that I did,  I only visualize POBTOT bars but  other bars are disappear
